# Text Copying Issue in PDF Generation on Ubuntu using PDFkit and Wkhtmltopdf, Works Fine on Windows

Tags: python, pdf, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf, python-pdfkit

I'm encountering an issue with copying text from a PDF generated using Python's pdfkit and wkhtmltopdf on Ubuntu. Strangely, the generated PDF appears as an image, preventing text copying. This problem is not present when generating the PDF on Windows, where everything works as expected.

Additionally, I'm facing challenges with the footer not displaying correctly on Ubuntu, further complicating the PDF generation process. Any insights or solutions to address these issues would be greatly appreciated.

I am using these options

```
options={
            'no-outline':None,
            'page-size': 'A4',
            'margin-top': '0.2in',
            'margin-bottom': '0.9in',
            'margin-right': '0.1in',
            'margin-left': '0.1in',
            'encoding': "utf-8",
            'footer-right': "Page [page] of [topage]",
            'footer-center':"""MadOverBuilding AI Private Limited I (mob)""",
            'footer-font-size': "8",
            'footer-spacing':8,
            'header-spacing':10,
            'header-font-size':"8",
            'custom-header': [
                ('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip')
            ],
            'no-outline': None
        }
```